# How to control the ABI for unions?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64, calling-convention, abi

I am working on a SIMD wrapper for C++, the base type looks like the following union:

```
union u{
    __m128d sse;
    double c[2]; 
};
```

In the following, I want to look at the ABI for Linux.

e.g.

```
__m128d f(__m128d a, __m128d b){
    return b;
}
```

compiles to

```
f(double __vector(2), double __vector(2)):
    vmovaps xmm0, xmm1
    ret
```

This uses the packed XMM registers for SIMD(the __m128d ABI). If I use the union instead it results in using the default float ABI.

```
f(u, u):
    vmovaps xmm1, xmm3
    vmovaps xmm0, xmm2
    ret
```

In this case, there is only one more instruction generated. But it can get worse, there are cases where I have to work with the stack, where I should only work with registers.

Is there a way to select the __m128d ABI explicitly?

Comment: Can you just pass the `__m128d` and limit use of the union to your function bodies?  I don't think there's a way to get gcc/clang to use an incompatible ABI (other than x86-64 System V or Windows x64) for unions without modifying their source code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes that would work, but would make my library ugly. I want it to be relatively accessable, but having to cast between ABI type and fiction body type is confusing

Comment: Wrapping the `__m128d` in a struct rather than a union seems to not cause this issue, then you can still add element accessors (which IMO are kind of dubious: using them would be usually be an anti-pattern), that doesn't answer this question it just works around the issue.

Comment: @harold: Good point, that's how Agner Fog's VCL does it (https://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass), with overloaded `[]` operators on a class or struct with a `__m128d` member, since this is C++.  (Which have to work for non-constant indices so they're potentially not very efficient.)

Comment: @PeterCordes That is basically what Harold said. I am going to try it out.

Comment: Right, I mostly wanted to point out that VCL exists, and you could copy from it if you want because Agner changed the licence to Apache in the last couple years, no longer GPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a step back for a moment, and compare this:

```cpp
union u{
    __m128d sse;
    double c[2]; 
};

double getx(u a){
    return a.c[0];
}

u add(u a, u b) {
    return { _mm_add_pd(a.sse, b.see) };
}
```

with this:

```cpp
double getx(__m128d a){
    return a[0];
}

__m128d add(__m128d a, __m128d b) {
    return _mm_add_pd(a, b);
}
```

Which do you prefer?

If this is a linux based ABI, and you're using clang or gcc, the latter will work just fine. So I'm not entirely sure what problem your union type is aiming to solve here?

**As an aside, it's generally a good idea to encourage users of your SIMD types to avoid accessing elements in the vector. With exception of accessing element 0, it's always going to incur a runtime cost, so avoid if possible.**

The spanner in the works for the above, is that visual C++ doesn't define these operators :( In that particular case, I'd only bother with a wrapper for Visual C+, and leave linux/Mac to use the native types e.g.

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
// If you want decent performance for Windows :(
#define VCALL __vectorcall
struct d128 {
    inline d128() = default;
    inline d128(const d128&) = default;
    inline d128(const __m128d v) { x = v; }
    __m128d x;
    inline VCALL operator __m128d() const { return x; }
    inline double VCALL operator [](int i) const { return ((const double*)(this))[i]; }
    inline double& VCALL operator [](int i) { return ((double*)(this))[i]; }
};
#else
#define VCALL 
typedef __m128d d128;
#endif
```

And now this work work nicely on all platforms:

```cpp
d128 VCALL add(d128 a, d128 b){
    return _mm_add_pd(a, b);
}
```

As will this:

```cpp
double VCALL getx(d128 a) {
    return a[0];
}
```

*(Well, under VC++ accessing individual elements is a little unpleasant, no matter which way you do it!)*

If you still insist on having a specific type *(because you want to overload the +, -, /, * operators)*, just be aware that gcc & clang have already overloaded all the common operators, so for gcc/clang I could have written:

```cpp
d128 VCALL add(d128 a, d128 b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: That works for FP vectors, but GNU C compatible compilers define `__m128i` as `typedef long long __attribute__((vector_size(16), may_alias))`, so `[]` `__m128i` only works for `int64_t` / `uint64_t` elements.  And of course that the `+` operator will give you `paddq`; you need your own typedefs or overloads if you want other integer element sizes.

Comment: BTW, you should also point out that `((double*)(this))[i]` is *only* safe in MSVC, so you can't just use that code across the board.  It violates strict-aliasing (pointing a `double*` into an object of a different type) and isn't guaranteed to be safe with gcc / clang.  You're only using it with MSVC, but that's an important note for future readers who might want to only take that part of your answer.

Comment: Also, for a C++ wrapper for `__m128d`, Agner Fog's VCL solves the convenience problem by providing implicit conversion cast operators to/from the underlying `__m128` / `__m128d` / `__m128i` type, so you can just pass your `Vec4f` to `_mm_shuffle_ps` when you want to use intrinsics instead of VCL functions, giving you the best of both worlds.  (You still get operator overloading for `v1 + v2` even on MSVC.)